# If the improper Riemann integral of $f(x)$ has conditional convergence on $[0,+\infty]$, whether the Lebesgue integral converges on $[0,+\infty]$?

Tags: real-analysis

If the improper Riemann integral of $f(x)$ has conditional convergence on $[0,+\infty]$, whether the Lebesgue integral of it converges on $[0,+\infty]$?

My attempt:
Let $f_+=\{f(x):f(x)>0,x\in[R,+\infty]\}$,$f_-=\{-f(x):f(x)<0,x\in[R,+\infty]\}$.

And let the partition of $[R,+\infty]$ as $\cup[R+\frac{k-1}{2^n},R+\frac{k}{2^n}]$ for $k=1,2,3...$ and $m_k^{(n,+)}=inf\{f_+(x):x\in[R+\frac{k-1}{2^n},R+\frac{k}{2^n}]\}$, $m_k^{(n,-)}=inf\{f_-(x):x\in[R+\frac{k-1}{2^n},R+\frac{k}{2^n}]\}$.

Then there exists
$$\int_{R}^{+\infty}\sum\chi_{[R+\frac{k-1}{2^n},R+\frac{k}{2^n}]}(m_k^{(n,+)}+m_k^{(n,-)})dx\le(L)\int_{R}^{+\infty}f_++f_-dx$$
and the left one equals to the lower Darboux sum of $|f(x)|$.

Then I'm not sure whether I can tell the lower Darboux sum of $|f(x)|$ is infinity. If I can tell so, as the Lebesgue integrability of $f(x)$ is as same as $|f(x)|$ then it is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: @user264745 Just update

Answer (score 1):

An easier (in my opinion) way to do it is the following: Since $f$ is conditionally integrable in the Riemann sense on $[0,\infty)$, we have that

$$\int_0^\infty \lvert f(x)\rvert ~\mathrm{d}x=\infty.$$

Now using the Monotone convergence theorem and the fact that the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide on compact intervals (under the assumption that the function is Riemann integrable, which we have) we have that

$$\int_{[0,\infty)}\lvert f\rvert~\mathrm{d}\lambda=\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_{[0,c]}\lvert f\rvert~\mathrm{d}\lambda=\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_0^c\lvert f(x)\rvert ~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty \lvert f(x)\rvert~\mathrm{d}x=\infty.$$

It follows that $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: (under the assumption that the function is Riemann integrable, which we have) cannot promote the conclusion that $|f(x)|$ satisfies the equation you mentioned, for we only have that $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable. What's more, I'm not sure that the theory that the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide on compact sets is right when it comes to improper integral.

Comment: Slight typo, meant compact intevals, I'll fix that. Anyways, the result that the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincides on compact intervals is very much applicable. The key thing is that I use it for the equality $\int_{[0,c]}\lvert f\rvert~\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_0^c \lvert f(x)\rvert~\mathrm{d}x$, i.e. on the compact set $[0,c]$, which is perfectly valued. The fact that $\lvert f\rvert$ is Riemann integrable on each compact set $[0,c]$ comes from the fact that $f$ is Riemann integrable on each compact set $[0,c]$, which comes from the conditional integrability of $f$.

Comment: It is important to remember that the improper Riemann integral is just defined as the limit of normal Riemann integrals.

Comment: "|f| is Riemann integrable on each compact set [0,c]" is not ture. The conditional integrability actually tells it is not Riemann integrable when c is large enough.

Comment: That is false. Conditional integrability tells us that $\lvert f\rvert$ is not integrable **in the limit**.

Comment: Take for example the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}~\mathrm{d}x$. This is conditionally convergent, but $\left\lvert\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right\rvert$ is still interable on each compact interval $[1,c]$ by continuity.